# Oriented surface, oriented curve, and vector field

Tags: surfaces, orientation

I have an oriented surface S and an oriented curve C. The surface and the curve intersect in points A and B. In A, the orientation of the curve is the same of the surface, in B they are in opposite directions. [image: See the image as an example]

There are two vector fields, $v$ and $u$. These vector fields are independent in every point. On S, they constitute the generators of the tangent space of S. I think that there must be a point along C in which the vector tangent to the curve is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

I have an intuitive and non-rigorous reason. The three vectors $v$, $u$, and $n$ (a vector giving the orientation of $S$) have the same orientation on the whole surface S: they are either right-handed or left-handed. Moving along C, I consider $v$, $u$, and $m$, where $m$ is the vector tangent to the curve. Then these three vectors must change from left-handed to right-handed (or vice-versa). In the point where the change takes place, $m$ must be in the plane generated by $u$ and $v$.

Is this true? In case, how can we prove this? Does this property have a name?

Comment: It makes no sense to say the curve has the same orientation as the surface; are you comparing the *tangent* vector of the curve with the *normal* vector of the surface? This is badly written: You are defining $u$ and $v$ to be vector fields on $S$ that are everywhere linearly independent on $S$. Do we even need that? Are you not just asking whether there is a point on $C$ where the tangent *line* to $C$ is parallel to the plane $S$? Consider the height function on $C$ given by the projection of $C$ onto the normal line to $S$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I understood that the "orientation" of the surface is identified by a vector which is not necessarily normal to the surface, just because the definition of orientation does not necessarily require the presence of a scalar product. The surfaces generate by the vectors $u$ and $v$ not necessarily parallel to S; they are parallel to S only on the surface S itself.

Comment: I see. I originally misunderstood what was going on. I think your proof is fine and is quite rigorous. The determinant $|u\ v\ m|$ changes from positive to negative as you move along the curve; it is a continuous function on the curve (why?) and hence must have a zero. At a zero the three vectors are linearly dependent; since $u,v$ are every where linearly independent, at that point, $m$ must be in their span.